# Filling my model from Facebook data (<FBGraphUser>)

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I created a model called User that have a property "name".

I'm making a request to facebook API (using the latest iOS SDK), the idea is set my user.name property when the facebook return the data.

The facebook return the data into the `startWithCompletionHandler` block, but I can't set this data to my user object, I only can access the data on `startWithCompletionHandler`. When I try access the data out of the block my model returns `NULL`.

How can I fill my model/object when facebook request returns?

My current method implementation:

```
+ (void)requestUserData:(User *)userModel {
    if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
     [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
       if(user.name) [self setUserData:user userModel:userModel];
     }];
   }
}

 + (void)setUserData:(NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)user userModel:(User *)userModel {
     userModel.name = user.name;
 }
```

And the call:

```
   __block User *user = [[User alloc] init];
   [GFFacebookHelpers requestUserData:user];
   NSLog(@"user: %@", user.name); //this part prints 2013-06-06 18:03:43.731 FacebookClassTest[74172:c07] user: (null)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to map the `FBGraphUser` data to your model or do you just have a `name` property on your model ?

Comment: Currently for test, I just have the "name" property, but after that this question is solved, I'll expand my model to store the facebook user basic data

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook's SDK is fetching asynchronously, so the completion handler you've written is executed after your helper method returns.

So when your method returns the User object of yours it is, logically just an empty user (since you alloc/init'ed it already).

When the completion block is invoked, that user object is updated but by this time, you're not processing it anymore in your app (view controller).

So here is my suggestion: Either use the Facebook SDK more directly from your view controllers, or if you want to keep all this logic in your helper class, then change it so your method doesn't return data, but it requires a block which will be invoked when the data request has finished, something more like this:

```
+ (void)requestUserDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(User *user, NSError *error))handler{
    if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {        
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if(!error){
                User *userData = [[User alloc] init];
                userData.name = user.name;

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    handler(userData, nil);
                });
            }
            else{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    handler(nil, error);
                });
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Note I've wrapped the invocation of the handler block in a `dispatch_async()` to the main queue to make sure you're good to go to update any UI.

Your view controller's method will now look like this:

```
- (void)updateStatusLabels {
    if([GFFacebookHelpers isLogged]){
        [GFFacebookHelpers requestUserDataWithCompletionHandler:^(User *user, NSError *error) {
            if(!error){
                self.fbStatus.text = user.name;
                [_loginButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }];
    }else{
        self.fbStatus.text = @"You need to login";

        [_loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel, I made a mistake on my code snippet example. I'm setting the userModel.name on this way: `userModel.name = user.name` without a loop. I fixed this on may post. I have already implemented your suggestion code, but I continue receiving NULL when I call `__block User *user = [[User alloc] init];` `[GFFacebookHelpers requestUserData:user];` `NSLog(@"user: %@", user.name);`

Comment: If you have a demo project I can download, I'll be happy to take a much closer look.

Comment: Daniel, I put the demo where I'm working here: git://github.com/godfather/facebookclasstest.git stay free to change what you want. PS.: I did some changes after the latest example that I have posted here Thanks

Comment: I forked your repo and changed some things and created a pull request for you to look at. Basically your request completion block is being fired after the method is returned of course because the Facebook SDK is asynchronously fetching data. So I added a callback block to your method. Now feels like a wrapper over a wrapper... but at least you can handle data errors in the helper class and keep the view controllers responsibility for showing/hiding parts of your app according to success/failure. Please take a look at your repo. I'll also update here my answer.